# ¿Por que me sale ese error?

Tags: python, csv, tablas, jupyter, typeerror

```
descendente = df[[df["ESTADO_EMPRESA"]=="Parcialmente operativa"] & df.sort_values[["PCT_VAR_VENTA"],ascending=False]]
descendente.head(15)

#esto es  lo que me tira el codigo
Input In [86]
    descendente = df[[df["ESTADO_EMPRESA"]=="Parcialmente operativa"] & df.sort_values[["PCT_VAR_VENTA"],ascending=False]]
                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Te sale el error porque esa no es la manera correcta de utilizar `sort_values`, no puedes filtrar un `dataframe` con un `sort_values` lo que debes hacer es aplicarle `sort_values` al `dataframe` que ha sido filtrado.

Por otra parte, la documentación de [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) es muy clara, no se utiliza con corchetes.

Como no pusiste tus datos cree un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar.

**Nota:** En el futuro por favor agrega siempre algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen para que las respuestas se apliquen mejor a tu caso.

Con el siguiente `dataframe` en el archivo "sample2.csv":

```
    col1    col2
0   1       11
1   2       12
2   3       13
3   4       14
4   5       15
5   6       16
6   7       17
7   8       18
8   9       19
9   10      20
```

Creando un filtro cualquiera (En tu caso el filtro sería `df["ESTADO_EMPRESA"]=="Parcialmente operativa"`), por ejemplo buscar todas las filas que `col1` sea par

```
df['col1']%2 == 0
```

Aplicando el filtro al `dataframe`

```
df[df['col1']%2 == 0]
```

Y aplicando `sort_values` a ese `dataframe` filtrado (En tu caso sería `sort_values("PCT_VAR_VENTA",ascending=False)`), por ejemplo, mostrar los valores de `col2` en forma descendente.

```
df[df['col1']%2 == 0].sort_values('col2', ascending=False)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
print(df[df['col1']%2 == 0].sort_values('col2', ascending=False))
```

Esto nos devuelve

```
    col1    col2
9   10      20
7   8       18
5   6       16
3   4       14
1   2       12
```

Te recomiendo siempre revisar la documentación oficial de `pandas` vienen ejemplos de como utilizar cada función

Comment: muchas me funciono, muchas gracias.

Comment: Buen día @RoyerAvalos, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo aparentemente ascending=false debe ir entre paréntesis. No Soy muy experto en Pandas, pero me parece que la sintaxis está mal, te copio una imagen que te puede servir (la bajé de https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/pandas-sort_values/)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intente con eso y aun me sale error, el codigo lo estoy haciendo en jupyterlab